# Android BitmapFactory.decodeStream loading BGR format?

Tags: opengl, android

It is very odd.I want to load .png file via asset manager which is provided by android sdk.
            AssetManager manager;
/........./
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(manager.open(path));

It returns BGR format data but opengl es 2.0 uses RGB format so , Blue seems red , red seems blue, how odd.

Is there any solution for it?

I use Nvıdia Tegra 2 (Android 2.2) device for test the application along with c++ via JNI.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the pixel-format to be `GL_BGR` instead of `GL_RGB`.

For [glTexImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) this would be the *format* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension: [EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888.txt). But, you need to check that your device can handle it. Galaxt Spica or Moment doesn't. Otherwise just do a conversion. In my engine, i swap BGRA to RGBA before loading into glTexImage.